# python import nltk error on Mac

Tags: python, nltk

I'm lost...

I followed the instruction to install NLTK on my Mac http://www.nltk.org/install.html

When I use the import nltk in the shell, no error message appears.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jan 10 2014, 11:23:15)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>
```

But using it in a file...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import nltk

print "test"
```

and running it, the interpreter is not able to find the module...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dummy.py", line 3, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: so solved it my myself....

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python is a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling it using PIP or homebrew or whatever you used to install it. If there is anything that says "error" and "clang" (Sorry I cannot remember the exact error) that means that it did not install correctly which could be because you don't have permission. Use the "sudo" command to run the command you use to install it just in case you don't have permissions.

Comment: The installation using pip is correct, as I said, the problem does not occur when I use #!/usr/bin/env python instead of #!/usr/bin/python. So everything is fine. I will anyway mark it as "solved"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$python
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```